# Typescript error on object fallback type declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
const pOptions = [{o: 123}]

const { id } = pOptions.find((o: any) => o.id === 123 ) || {}
```

I got error

`Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'`

How to solve this?

demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-eec3yq

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using stackblitz, etc. to show the issue happening.

Comment: @palaѕн thanks, stackblitz is fast

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what's wrong - you have `{}` and you expect to get `id` from it but that property doesn't exist. TypeScript is doing what it can - analyses the structure of your object and finds that it doesn't match. Either have your fallback as `{id: undefined}` or use optional chaining or something.

Comment: Your demo also shows that you don't even have an ID in the object you are searching. As a side note, questions should be self-contained - if that link goes down, now that information is gone.

Comment: Did you mean using `const pOptions = [{id: 123}]` instead of `const pOptions = [{o: 123}]`?

Comment: You're trying to get the `id` from object that doesn't have such a property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript is giving you `Property 'id' does not exist on type{}'` because there is no `id` in the array of object.

```
const pOptions = [{id: 123}];
const { id } = pOptions.find((o:any) => o.id === 123 ) || {};
```

Please let me know if this solves your issue. Thanks!